# Naming convention for Django migrations

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

Is there a best practice naming convention for Django migrations?

If it's a small migration the names are pretty obvious, but things get harry when multiple fields are being changed. Just wondering if anyone has a standard they like to use.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to add some meaningful name instead of auto generated one docs specify you should do:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --name changed_my_model your_app_label
```

so I think you should give some short info and app label.

when you are writing your own migrations and changing a lot of fields maybe separating them can be good idea to keep names short.

But personally I don't see the point to change generated names.